# Zend_exception vs Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception (PDO Exception Handling)

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, pdo, exception

I am looking to further myself in the development of Zend PHP.

I was hoping someone could lead me to answer regarding exception handlers...

Is the `Zend_Db_Adapter_exception $e` function and the `Zend_exception $e` one in the same?  Does one catch both instances?

```
} catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->log($e, Zend_Log::ERR);
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
```

VS

```
    }catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->log($e, Zend_Log::ERR);
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
```

#### p.s

Should anybody be interested for further reference... `PDOException` vs. the above at: [PDOException vs Zend Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496234/pdo-exception-handler-vs-zend-exceptions)

Comment: Please ask ONE question per QUESTION.

Comment: META MEDIIIIIIIC!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `Zend_Exception` is the base exception which the Zend Framework throws. It actually extends `Exception` so if you catch `Zend_Exception` most likely it would be something thrown from the framework or yourself (in the code you have written)

`Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception` on the other hand is again an exception defined by Zend Framework but it is only thrown when there is a problem with the execution of the DB statement (or not being able to connect properly to the DB).

The same way `Zend_Exception` compared to `Exception`, is specifically made to represent exceptions thrown from the framework, the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception` is made to represent exceptions thrown from the DB access mechanisms in ZF compared to the generic PDOException.

To summarize, when you use Zend Framework, you should catch the Zend specific exceptions since the framework is made that way to throw them so I guess there shouldn't be any chance of having a PDOException or a normal Exception thrown from the framework itself, unless you have thrown one in your own part of the code.

Comment: since `Zend_Db_adapter_exception` is an extension of `Zend_Exception`, could'nt I not include the catch for `Z_E` and it would be thrown regardless as you said `in the framework or yourself`

Comment: Well, if you exclude `Zend_Exception` then most likely anything which is not a `Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception` might be thrown from the framework (in specific cases). So, yes, it would be thrown and if you not handle it will fail.